# c# setup project

Tags: .net, installation, arguments, project

c# visual studio 2008 , setup project ,file types on targed machine, &open-> Arguments
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ehs907t(VS.71).aspx

in this section i can write only characters, how can i specify file name (to open).

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the %1 variable, so if all you wanted to pass as arguments to your exe is the file name, then use:

```
"%1"
```

As the arguments. If you wanted to precede it with a command, say, "/open", you'd use:

```
/open "%1"
```